# What's preferred among liftM, lilftA, etc

Tags: haskell

Lately I've been writing FFI code that returns a data structure in the IO monad. For example:

```
peek p = Vec3 <$> (#peek aiVector3D, x) p
              <*> (#peek aiVector3D, y) p
              <*> (#peek aiVector3D, z) p
```

Now I can think of four nice ways to write that code, all closely related:

```
peek p = Vec3 <$> io1 <*> io2 <*> io3
peek p = liftA3 Vec3 io1 io2 io3
peek p = return Vec3 `ap` io1 `ap` io2 `ap` io3
peek p = liftM3 Vec3 io1 io2 io3
```

Notice that I'm asking about monadic code that doesn't require anything beyond what `Applicative` provides. What is the preferred way to write this code? Should I use `Applicative` to emphasize what the code does, or should I use `Monad` because it might (?) have optimizations over `Applicative`?

The question is slightly complicated by the fact that there are only `[liftA..liftA3]` and `[liftM..liftM5]` but I have several records with more than three or five members, so if I decide to go with `lift{A,M}` I lose some consistency because I would have to use a different method for the larger records.

Comment: Consistency speaks for `ap` or `<*>`. Which you choose is largely a matter of taste. My preference (and I have the impression that is not mine alone) is `<*>`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The first thing to remember is that this is slightly more complicated than it ought to be--any `Monad` instance *should* have an associated `Applicative` instance such that the `liftM` and `liftA` functions coincide. As such, here's two guidelines:

- If you're writing a generic function for *any* `Monad`, use `liftM` &co. to avoid incompatibility with other functions that have only a `Monad` constraint.
- If you're working with a specific `Monad` instance that you know has an accompanying `Applicative` instance, use `Applicative` operators consistently for any definition or subexpression where you don't need `Monad` operations, but avoid mixing them aimlessly.

> Should I use `Applicative` to emphasize what the code does, or should I use `Monad` because it might (?) have optimizations over `Applicative`?

In general, if there is a difference, it will be the other way around. `Applicative` only supports a static "structure" of the computation, whereas `Monad` permits embedded control flow. Consider lists, for instance--with `Applicative`, all you can do is generate all possible combinations and transform each one--the number of result elements is determined entirely by the number of elements in each input. With `Monad`, you can generate different numbers of elements at each step based on input elements, allowing you to filter or expand arbitrarily.

A more potent example is is the `Applicative` and `Monad` instances based on zipping infinite streams--`Applicative` can simply zip them together in the obvious way, whereas `Monad` has to recalculate lots of stuff that it then throws away.

So, the final issue is of `liftA2 f x y` vs. `f <$> x <*> y`, or the `Monad` equivalents. My advice here would be the following guidelines:

- If you're writing every argument out anyway, use the infix form, because it's easier to read for large expressions.
- If you're just lifting an existing function, use `foo = liftA2 bar` rather than `foo x y = bar <$> x <*> y`--it's shorter and more clearly expresses what you're doing.

And finally, on the issue of consistency, there's no reason you couldn't simply define your own `liftA4` and so on, if you need them.

Comment: Actually, I think that `liftM*` might be slightly faster because they use fewer binds than the `Applicative` operators when the typical `pure = id; (<*>) = ap` instance is used. But the difference, if any, should be negligible.

Comment: I didn't know if there would be a correct answer, but I think this is it.

Comment: @ehird, as a counterpoint to that, sometimes it is possible to implement applicative instances that are smarter about optimization than monad instances can be.

Comment: @ehird: Negligible or not, I'd be surprised if anything that trivial survived GHC's optimization anyhow.

Comment: @luqui: Certainly, but I would say that most monads — `IO`, `ST`, `STM`, and all of `transformers`, for example — don't have such implementations. Still, GHC is likely to optimise away the difference.